# bearing in iphone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

i want to make a compass bearing in iphone. like there will be a circle in the corner and it will have 'v' shape drawn inside. so when i start my camera and move than i shlould see the markers... but my first question is 
a) how to make that circle in the corner whose center will be my current location. so now if i find any point at particular lat long than it should appear as dot in the quadrant.

Comment: Downvote for broken grammar. Difficult to read.